# ¿Cómo lograr tomar el datetime del formulario en ajax en formato php?

Tags: php, ajax, datetime

Muy buenas.
He estado tratando de resolver mi problema específico, y he investigado si es posible realizar en ajax por el caso de la tabla que esta creada en phpmyadmin, por lo que en la tabla, fecha_creacion contiene datetime al igual que el formulario, pero el ajax en php no me lo toma por la fecha actual y la hora actual. Adjunto el error para que comprendan mi problema:

[image: Fecha Creacion de datetime]

Como verán, eso es lo que he estado tratando de resolver, estos son los códigos a continuación y la tabla correspondiente:

**`Tabla Usuarios`**

```html
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
 `Id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Usuario` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Nombre` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Apellido` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Id_perfil` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Id_estado` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Fecha_Creacion` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id_usuario`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Id_perfil` (`Id_perfil`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Id_estado` (`Id_estado`),
 CONSTRAINT `usuarios_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_perfil`) REFERENCES `perfil` (`id_perfil`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `usuarios_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_estado`) REFERENCES `estado` (`id_estado`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**`Indexusuario.php`**

```html
<?php 
 error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="es-ES" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="es-ES" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="es-ES">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<!-- Jquery -> Libs -->
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Caracteres UTF-8 -->
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <title>Index Usuarios</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
   width: 100%
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  th, td {
   border: none;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
 </style>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   //boton anadir
   $(".anadir").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // obteniendo el id desde el boton.
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    //alert (id);

    // valores añadidos.
    var id_usuario = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_usuario').val();
    var usuario = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.usuario').val();
    var nombre = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.nombre').val();
    var apellido = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.apellido').val();
    var id_perfil = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_perfil').val();
    var id_estado = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_estado').val();
    var password = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.password').val();
    var fecha_creacion = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.fecha_creacion').val();

    $.post('control_usuanad.php', {
     //variable caso anadir.
     Caso:'anadir',
     Id_usuario:id_usuario,
     Usuario:usuario,
     Nombre:nombre,
     Apellido:apellido,
     Id_perfil:id_perfil,
     Id_estado:id_estado,
     Password:password,
     Fecha_Creacion:fecha_creacion
    },function(e){
     alert(e);
    });
   });

   //boton editar
   $(".editar").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id_usuario = $(this).attr('data-id');

    var usuario = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.usuario').val();
    var nombre = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.nombre').val();
    var apellido = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.apellido').val();
    var id_perfil = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_perfil').val();
    var id_estado = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.id_estado').val();
    var password = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.password').val();
    var fecha_creacion = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('.fecha_creacion').val();

    $.post('control_usuario.php', {
     Caso:'editar',
     Id_usuario:id_usuario,
     Usuario:usuario,
     Nombre:nombre,
     Apellido:apellido,
     Id_perfil:id_perfil,
     Id_usuario:id_usuario,
     Id_estado:id_estado,
     Password:password,
     Fecha_Creacion:fecha_creacion
    },function(e){
     alert(e);
    });
   });

   // boton eliminar
   $(".eliminar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_usuario = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();

    $.post('control_usuario.php', {
     Caso: 'eliminar',
     Id_usuario:id_usuario
    }, function(e){
     alert(e);
    });
   });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
 require_once 'conexionrem.php';

 $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();

 if($stmt->num_rows>0){
  echo "
   <div style='overflow-x:auto;'>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Id_usuario</th>
      <th>Usuario</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Id_perfil</th>
      <th>Id_estado</th>
      <th>password</th>
      <th>Fecha_Creacion</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
     </tr>
 ";

 $stmt->bind_result($id_usuario,$usuario,$nombre,$apellido,$id_perfil,$id_estado,$password,$fecha_actual);
 while ($stmt->fetch()){
  echo "

   <tr>
    <td><input type=hidden class='myid' value='$id_usuario'/>$id_usuario</td>
    <td><input type=text class=usuario value='$usuario' placeholder='Usuario:' /></td>
    <td><input type=text class=nombre value='$nombre' placeholder='Nombre:' /></td>
    <td><input type=text class=apellido value='$apellido' placeholder='Apellido:' /></td>
    <td><input type=text class=id_perfil value='$id_perfil' placeholder='Id_perfil:' /></td>
    <td><input type=text class=id_estado value='$id_estado' placeholder='Id_Estado:' /></td>
    <td><input type=secret class=password value='$password' placeholder='Password:' /></td>
    <td><input type=text class='$fecha' value='<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago'); echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>' placeholder='FechaCreacion:'/></td>
   </tr>
  ";
 } $stmt->close();

 echo " 
   </table>
  </div>
 ";
} else {
 $stmt->close();
 echo "<h3>No se encontró ningun registro.</h3>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y por último, me he preguntado si en el caso del anadir (`control_usuanad.php`) es correcto para el formato de datetime?

**`control_usuanad.php`**

```html
<?php 
$id_usuario = $usuario = $nombre = $apellid = $id_perfil = $id_estado = $password = $fecha_actual = NULL;

if($_POST['Caso']=='anadir') {
 $id_usuario = $_POST['Id_usuario'] ?: '';
 $usuario = $_POST['Usuario'] ?: '';
 $nombre = $_POST['Nombre'] ?: '';
 $apellido = $_POST['Apellido'] ?: '';
 $id_perfil = $_POST['Id_perfil'] ?: '';
 $id_estado = $_POST['Id_estado'] ?: '';
 $password = $_POST['Password'] ?: '';
 require_once 'conexionrem.php';
 $stmt = $c->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(id_usuario, usuario, nombre, apellido, id_perfil, id_estado, password, fecha_creacion) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("isssiiss", $id_usuario,$usuario,$nombre,$apellido,$id_perfil,$id_estado,$password,$fecha_actual);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 echo "Usuario añadido";
}
```

Espero sus respuestas y comentarios al respecto.
Saludos!

Comment: Saca el date_default_timezone_set del input, ponlo al principio del archivo. También puedes usar SYSDATE() en su lugar, que en MySQL va a rellenar la fecha del sistema.

Comment: Hice esta parte como me comentó, aun asi no me lee el date.

Comment: No me dí cuenta que estaba dentro de un echo, te he puesto una respuesta porque aquí no iba a caber. Espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Además de sacar el 'date_default_timezone_set' del input, si está dentro de un echo no necesitas la etiqueta php para rellenar el value:

```
echo "

            <tr>
                <td><input type='hidden' class='myid' value='$id_usuario'/>$id_usuario</td>
                <td><input type='text' class='usuario' value='$usuario' placeholder='Usuario:' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='nombre' value='$nombre' placeholder='Nombre:' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='apellido' value='$apellido' placeholder='Apellido:' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='id_perfil' value='$id_perfil' placeholder='Id_perfil:' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='id_estado' value='$id_estado' placeholder='Id_Estado:' /></td>
                <td><input type='secret' class='password' value='$password' placeholder='Password:' /></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='fecha_creacion' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' placeholder='FechaCreacion:'/></td>
            </tr>
        ";
```

Si no estuvieran los campos dentro del echo entonces sería correcto utilizar la etiqueta de php. He cambiado el nombre de la clase 'fecha' a 'fecha_creacion' que es como la recoges más adelante para enviar los datos, supongo que es a lo que correspondía el valor de la variable $fecha que usabas para asignar la clase.

Comment: Aunque he resuelto el problema del fecha date del día de hoy, utilizando este código del inicio:
`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
 date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
 $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
Y al poner al value, sirvio por la fecha y la hora actual que es lo que rellena completamente. Pero trataré con tu código, veré si es que puede tomar los demás fechas pasadas en el base de datos. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Lo que hace el código que he puesto es equivalente a lo que has hecho, tu has guardado la fecha en una variable intermedia $currentDateTime y yo la he puesto directamente en el input, así que has encontrado la solución. Sólo como nota ya que estás modificando el archivo, sería más rápido y sencillo poner un atributo id y/o nombre a los inputs y recoger los valores por estos atributos en lugar de recorrer las casillas de la tabla, quedaría más limpio.

Comment: tienes razón, me doy cuenta que en la tabla de usuario, al tratar de añadir un registro, aparece "root" en vez de poner rellenar el nombre del usuario en phpmyadmin, trataré de ordenar bien.

Comment: Aun persiste el problema, cada vez que añado, sigue leyendo root del nombre del usuario y el password no esta (aunque sé que puse secret, no se lee en el registro en la tabla)

Comment: Para las contraseñas utiliza input type="password", no sé que hace secret. En cuanto al usuario, utilizas una clase llamada myid pero luego recoges una clase llamada id_usuario, creo que ahí está el error, por esto te comentaba lo del atributo id.

Comment: Aunque haya cambiado ese atributo, no deja añadir, el myid aun funciona siendo que la tabla del id_usuario lleva AI (autoincrement), pero el nombre del usuario se lee todavía "root" (eso es lo más extraño) y cambie el type del password y no lo añade al tabla, todo lo demás si (nombre y apellido, los id_perfil y estado, también fecha creacion).

Comment: Baku si el id_usuario es un autoincrement no se añade este campo en el insert, se crea automáticamente al crear el nuevo registro. Por otro lado vas a tener que ver el valor que adquiere la variable usuario en cada paso, ya que en algún momento está reeemplanzando el valor por root, probablemente tengas otra variable $usuario="root" en algún archivo por ejemplo para gestionar la conexión a la base de datos. Hazlo con echo para php y alert para js, o si manejas las herramientas de desarrollador de chrome lo puedes ir viendo en el navegador.

Comment: tenías razón, por alguna razón la gestión de base de datos (`conexionrem.php`) fue tomada por los nombres de la tabla, asi que modifiqué un poco por el idioma inglés y algunas sensibilidades (mayusculas con minisculas) y al comprobarlo, funciona sin problemas, toma todo lo que quería, exactamente igual lo escrito. Espero que esto pueda resolver a varios que aún practican el ajax. Muchas gracias por tus comentarios y ayuda.

Comment: No hay de que, estupendo que ya lo tengas :)